# Edx Studio not showing with a theme

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mako, edx

The Studio app that is served on port `18010` shows with no theme. It only shows black text on a white background and with no images... that happens while the other counterpart LMS (on port `80`) app shows fine.

Where shall I start troubleshooting this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The edX Studio does not support to theme.**

If you are not able to see the default pictures
Use following commands to update asset files

```
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
```

Answer (score 0):

port 18010 is forwaded via nginx, So you have to run studio collectstatic.
ie..update_assets for cms(studio) in edx.